# Creating a count down list of numbers and string using loops and going in steps of 3

Tags: loops, for-loop, function-definition

I have to generate a count down list that stops before the numbers become negative. The list has to go in steps of 3, for instance, 60, 57, 54. However, when the number is even it should print the string 'even' and when odd it should print the number, for instance, even, 57, even, 51, even, etc.
The count down should be displayed as starting from 60, but it should work for any integer starting value.

This is my attempt:
def IsEven(counter):
if (counter % 1 == 0):
out = counter
else:
type(counter)=='even'

def count_down(list):

```
#loop over every value of the list

for counter in list:
    counter=counter-3            
return counter
```

list1=[range(60,0)]
count_down(list1)

Comment: Does it work? What is the question?

Comment: here you're not calling `isEven` function at all how it is supposed to work?